# Usage of no ... nor

Tags: grammar, expressions

Usage of neither ... nor is well understood.

I changed the sentence (1) to the sentence (2) to give a focus on the word 'no' in front of 'data'.

> (1) Data are neither generated nor transferred.
>
> (2) No data are generated nor transferred.

Is sentence (2) is natural-sounding?

Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: From my BrE perspective, the "orphaned" ***nor*** in #2 is nowhere near as unnatural as plural ***data***. But the switch to singular has been [quite marked in AmE as well](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+data+are+stored%2Cthe+data+is+stored&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20data%20are%20stored%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20data%20is%20stored%3B%2Cc0) over recent decades.

Comment: (AmE here) It's "neither...nor, either...or, or no...or." Data *is* neither generated nor transferred/No data *is* generated or transferred" sounds natural to me (again, AmE). (Oh, and I'm not in IT. But I read a lot of scientific papers which analyze data.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a straight answer to your questions, (2) is grammatically fine, but not idiomatic.

The construction *no … nor* is certainly understandable but not common. On the other hand, (1), *neither … nor* is a long-standing clause that fits perfectly into your sentence.

Despite this, I'd go with the phrasing *"Data are not generated nor transferred"* which would convey the meaning just as well, while sounding idiomatic.

In the comments, people have been more concerned with your use of the (<strike>correct</strike>) plural verb with *data*. As [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Data+is%2CData+are&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CData%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdata%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BData%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CData%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdata%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BData%20are%3B%2Cc0) analysis of word usage agrees, the plural form is more common with this, a plural noun.

Comment: _Is_ (2) grammatically fine?  Certainly if _or_ were substituted for _nor_, it would be grammatical and idiomatic.  As it is, it sure feels wrong.

Comment: Perhaps this is a Transatlantic thing: in BrE, you use nor when talking about something you also do not do.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. "Data are not generated nor transferred" is incorrect usage as it is ambiguously parsable. e.g. "Data are not: 1) generated, 2) not transferred", introducing a double negative. You would need "Data are not generated nor are they transferred" in order to disambiguate. Not-nor is fine as long as it has a single parsing. See this great article https://www.manhattanprep.com/gmat/blog/gmat-grammar-using-nor-without-neither/